# Where does the '42' come from?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
php > echo '1 + 5' * '42 + 1' . "\n";
42
```

I was expecting some sort of error or warning, but PHP lets us multiply strings without complaint. However, why does it display the first integer from the second string?

Some more examples, for which I can find no real logical reason behind the results:

```
php > echo '1 hi' * '42 + 1' . "\n";
42
php > echo 'hi' * '42 + 1' . "\n";
0
php > echo '1 + 5' * '42 + hi' . "\n";
42
php > echo '1 + 5' * '42 hi' . "\n";
42
php > echo '1 + 5' * '42hi' . "\n";
42
```

Comment: **8** ? I don't have any idea of which 8 you are talking about ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: And https://eval.in/130579

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the FM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP tries to convert the strings to numbers on the fly and does the math based on what it gets. When a string starts with a non-number it is converted to a zero - hence your answers.

When PHP converts these, it is done in a left to right fashion:

The string `1 + 5` actually converts to the number 1 - then the `42 + 1` converts to 42. Your statement is therefore 1 * 42 and the result is an echo of 42. The statement you have with the zero answer, you try to multiply `hi` (which is cast as zero) and therefore you get a result of zero.

Edit: As for why it is echo'ing out the answer rather than the strings - that's simply due to operator precedence. Math operators are ranked higher than string operators - so it treats it as something it should work out then echo over something it should echo out as it stands.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that the strings were being cast to ints, and then the product was being recast to string. With that stated, the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: No probs, PHP is a funny thing. Sometimes you can read the manual for hours and not find what you want, other times you just happen across the right answer when you look for it - oh and when you think you have worked out every trick PHP has, it tricks you again.